# How do I get the user's ip who is accesing website's url?

Tags: jsp

I have been trying to get user's ip using the following code and I got this output :

> InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(): ankur-PC
>
> InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(): 10.0.0.2
>
> request.getLocalAddr(): 0.0.0.0
>
> request.getLocalName(): 0.0.0.0
>
> request.getRemoteAddr(): 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
>
> request.getRemoteHost(): 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
>
> request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP"): null
>
> request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP"): null
>
> request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR"): null
>
> InetAddress.getByName(request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")):
>   localhost/127.0.0.1
>
> InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteAddr()): /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
>
> InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteHost()): /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

I don't know its correct or not. Please suggest me something as I am new to this.

```
    /*
 * getClientIP.java
 *
 * Created on July 9, 2011, 12:13 AM
 */

//package org.com.testing;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.net.*;



public class getClient extends HttpServlet {

   // Translation translation = new Translation();

    /** Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<!-- Copy right 2009-2012 Redecis Systems Inc. All Rights Reserved. -->");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>::: Redecis Systems :::</title>");
        out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">");
        out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"0\">");
        out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
        out.println("<meta name=\"Author\" CONTENT=\"Kevin\">");
        out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"JS/Standar.css\" type=\"text/css\">");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"JS/Standar.js\" language=\"JavaScript\"></script>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<table width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"center\" valign=\"middle\">");

        out.println("<table class=\"tableBorder\" width=\"50%\" height=\"35%\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"> ");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");

        out.println("<table class=\"darkBlue\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\"> ");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName():</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress():</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td width=\"65%\" align=\"right\">request.getLocalAddr():</td>");
        out.println("<td width=\"35%\" align=\"left\">" + request.getLocalAddr() + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">request.getLocalName():</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + request.getLocalName() + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td width=\"65%\" align=\"right\">request.getRemoteAddr():</td>");
        out.println("<td width=\"35%\" align=\"left\">" + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">request.getRemoteHost():</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + request.getRemoteHost() + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");


        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">request.getHeader(\"Proxy-Client-IP\"):</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP") + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">request.getHeader(\"WL-Proxy-Client-IP\"):</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP") + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">request.getHeader(\"X-FORWARDED-FOR\"):</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">InetAddress.getByName(request.getHeader(\"X-FORWARDED-FOR\")):</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + InetAddress.getByName(request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")) + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteAddr()):</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteAddr()) + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td align=\"right\">InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteHost()):</td>");
        out.println("<td align=\"left\">" + InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteHost()) + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("</table>");

        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");

        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");

        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.close();
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** Returns a short description of the servlet.
     */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.`request.getRemoteAddr()`returns the clients IP.
The only catch is when the user is behind a proxy. Using this will return the proxy server's address. To retrieve the client's ip in that case we use`request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")`